# unable to ping local network

Tags: macos, network, ping

I have a problem whereby Mac A cannot ping the local network. It can ping the router, 192.168.1.1 but none of the machines on that network. Mac B works properly.

- I am running yosemite 10.10 on both macs.
- I've tried deleting the network settings and starting again (on Mac A)

This is also preventing (which) mac from discovering my SONOS network (which is or isn't different than the local network??).

Comment: What procedure are you following to "delete the network settings" and "starting again"? Are you following an Apple Support article?  Physically how does Mac A connect to the local network. How does Mac B connect to the network?

Comment: I deleted all the wireless networks in the network preference and restarted. Both macs connect wirelessly.

Comment: My original comment should have read SONOS network not sons lol

Comment: Thanks! It's best to edit the post so that the text reads correctly...

Comment: For a good analysis - could you please show a graphic or explain in more details how your network is set up? For me it sounds like we have a network for Wifi and different one for lan and the routes between those two are missing. Mac A is in the Wifi and Mac B is located in the LAN.

If I'm wrong with this assumption, please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

Ping can be suppressed by a firewall, so I like to take a more overall view.

- I would choose one thing that Macs can share like Screen Sharing and File Sharing and turn them on on both Macs.
- I would check if the time of day is correct on both (since some deviation past a few hundred seconds can cause visibility errors in some sharing tasks). This also ensures that the network connection to internet time servers is working if you set the time automatically.
- Now that you know the network itself is functional for each Mac - open Finder in both and search for the other Mac.

If you have hidden the "shared" sidebar in finder, you might have to un-hide it. Alternatively, you could make a new test user account on both Macs and use it for troubleshooting. The default Finder settings will show shared Macs on the local network.

At that point, you'll know a bit more about the network and possibly want to power off both Macs and power off the router and then start them all up again.

Comment: both macs can share screens with each other.  The problem is related to connecting from the wifi to the wired lan on the router. Now both macs cannot access the wired lan from the wifi lan, I have an android phone which can and an iPad which also can. Its just the macs with this particular router (SFR NB6 I'm in France)